# asp sql server connection and table

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 <title>SOP</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left">

<%
selectdata= "Select * from dbo.sop"


set RScontest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RScontest.ActiveConnection = "dsn=test123 ;uid=test123;pwd=test123"
RScontest.Source = SelectData
RScontest.CursorType = 3
RScontest.CursorLocation = 2
RScontest.LockType = 1
RScontest.Open()
if not(rscontest.bof) and not(rscontest.eof) then%>
%>

<table BORDER="1" align="center" width="640">
<caption>SOP</caption>
<tr>
<td>Order</td>
<td>Department</td>
<td>DOC Type</td>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Revision</td>
<td>DOC</td>
<td>Active</td>

<%
 while not rscontest.eof
%>

<tr>
<td>
<%= rs("order") %>
</td>

<td>
<%= rs("Department") %>
</td>

<td>
<%= rs("[DOC Type]") %>
</td>

<td>
<%= rs("Title") %>
</td>

<td>
<%= rs("Revision") %>
</td>

<td>
<%= rs("DOC") %>
</td>

<td>
<%= rs("Active") %>
</td>

 <%
' Move to the next record
rs.movenext
' Loop back to the do statement
loop %>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<%
' Close and set the recordset to nothing
rs.close
set rs=nothing
%>
```

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'  is the error I am getting.

Can you check this also, if you can help me with an OLEDB way to connect instead? I tryed my self and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show you defining or opening a database connection.

You need to define that first and then pass it into the recordset with the query you want to execute

Details of opening a connection here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx

A code example from that MDSN article:

```
Sub ConnectionExample6()
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

   ' Open a connection by referencing the ODBC driver.
   cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
      "server=MySqlServer;uid=MyUserName;pwd=MyPassword;database=pubs"
   cnn.Open

   ' Create a Recordset by executing an SQL statement.
   Set rs = cnn.Execute("Select * From authors")

   ' Show the first author.
   MsgBox rs("au_fname") & " " & rs("au_lname")

   ' Close the connection.
   rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: but the way i add the table is correct, and how could i do this oledb style.